# Google Sheets script crashes on getLastRow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been working on a script that takes incoming data in sections, sets each section onto the sheet, then formats it accordingly. It ran well with no problems several times in a row, on both an empty sheet and on with previous data before the error first occurred.

The error occurs when the code calls `sheet.getLastRow()` during the third (out of five) iteration of the loop as seen here[image]. I didn't notice anything out of place in the debug data[image] so I assumed the error must be in the call to `getLastRow`. I refactored the code without `getLastRow` but the same error occurs on another line when attempting to apply row banding[image]

Both of these calls[image] work fine the first 2 times through the loop. Why not the third??

```
// For each section apply it to sheet

sections.forEach( function(x) {

    var sect = collectionOfSections[x];

    if (!sect) return;

    // If sheet empty apply to first row, otherwise apply after last row + spacing
    var row = (sheet.getLastRow())
        ? sheet.getLastRow() + spacing
        : 1;

    // Grab the first cell of range
    var cell = sheet.getRange(row, 1);

    if (sect.length === 1) {
    // Format according to length and content

        cell.offset(0, 0, 1, sect[0].length)
            .setValues(sect)
            .setBackground(colors[0])
            .setHorizontalAlignment('center')
            .setFontFamily(fontFamily)
            .setFontWeight('bold')
            .setFontSize(
                (x===sections[0])
                    ? e_fontSizes[0]
                    : e_fontSizes[1]
            );

        cell.offset(0, 0, 1, sect[0].filter( function(y) {return y === ''} ).length + 1)
            .merge()
            .setFontStyle('italic');

        cell.offset(0, sect[0].length - 1, 1, maxWidth - sect[0].length + 1)
            .merge()
            .setBackground(
                (x === sections[0])
                    ? colors[0]
                    : colors[2]
            );

    } else {

        cell.offset(0, 0, 1, maxWidth)
            .merge()
            .setValue(sect[0][0])
            .setBackground(colors[0])
            .setHorizontalAlignment('center')
            .setFontSize(e_fontSizes[1] + 1)
            .setFontWeight('bold')
            .setFontFamily(fontFamily)
            .setFontStyle('italic');

        cell.offset(1, 0, 1, sect[1].length)
            .setValues([sect[1]])
            .setHorizontalAlignment('center')
            .setFontFamily(fontFamily)
            .setFontSize(e_fontSizes[1])
            .setFontWeight('bold');

        // for loop start 2, set Values then iterate through each and format accordingly
        for (var i = 2; i < sect.length; i++) {

            cell.offset(i, 0, 1, sect[i].length)
                .setValues([sect[i]])
                .setFontFamily(fontFamily)
                .setFontSize(e_fontSizes[1]);

            sect[i].forEach( function(y, j) {

                if(!isNaN(y) && y.toString().length > 9) cell.offset(i , j, 1, 1).setHorizontalAlignment('center').setNumberFormat(phoneFormat);
                if(y.toString().indexOf('@') > -1) cell.offset(i, j, 1, 1).setHorizontalAlignment('center');
            });

        }   // Apply row banding around content
        cell.offset(1, 0, sect.length - 1, maxWidth)
            .applyRowBanding()
            .setHeaderRowColor(colors[1])
            .setFirstRowColor(colors[2])
            .setSecondRowColor(colors[3]);
    }

    if (x != sections[0]) {
    // If not first section, give section a named range
        var range;
        if (sect.length > 2) range = cell.offset(2, 0, sect.length - 2, maxWidth);
        else range = cell.offset(0, sect[0].length - 1, 1, maxWidth - sect[0].length + 1);

        sheet.getParent()
            .setNamedRange(sheet.getName() + '_' + x, range);
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't see where the **sheet** variable is declared and assigned... May be, it is undefined.

Comment: **sheet** is declared and extensively used previously in this function. The code couldn't reach this far if it was undefined and it still shows a value for sheet in the debugger.

Comment: Try adding `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` in the loop after setting named range.

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is possibly has to do with `sheet.getParent().setNamedRange(sheet.getName()+'_'+x, range);`
but not line #135.

It's not clear why and it's not documented anywhere but setNamedRange() sometimes doesn't allow you to have sheet names in the range name string. Try to modify the naming of the range somehow.

Comment: Without the sheet name will a different sheet with the same name for a range cause a conflict? The ranges are named according to the section it occupies, different sheets with the same sections would have the same name for a range.

Comment: After reading your answer I delved into rules for Named Ranges and compared each sheet name against the rules. I found out some sheets contained spaces in their names and one starts with a number, both of which are illegal for named ranges. After changing the name to accommodate this everything runs fine. Thank you so much for the help